# Limit SQL query result in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, pagination

I would like to limit the amount of rows I fetch in MySQL. Can you show me how?

ex:

- 1st query I would like to retrieve only the first 10,000 records
- 2nd query I would like to retrieve only records from 10,000 - 20,000

etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/MySQL Pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095474/php-mysql-pagination)

Answer (score 11):

The term you're looking for is "pagination." Unfortunately, this is done differently depending on the SQL engine.

For MS SQL Server, see this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-ms-sqlserver).

Since you mentioned MySQL, it's actually quite simple:

```
SELECT [columns] FROM [a table] LIMIT 10000
SELECT [columns] FROM [a table] LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 10000
```

The first statement fetches results 1-10,000, and the second statement fetches results 10,001-20,000.

Answer (score 5):

I think the following queries will give you the desired result

> SELECT * FROM PERSON_TBL LIMIT 0, 10000

@ 1st query I would like to retrieve only the first 10,000 records

> SELECT * FROM PERSON_TBL LIMIT 10000,10000

@ 2nd query I would like to retrieve only records from 10,000 - 20,000

Answer (score 3):

```
select top x * from table in SQL Server

select * from table where ROWNUM < x in Oracle

select * from table limit x in MySQL
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL and PostgreSQL support `OFFSET` that is usually used with a `LIMIT` clause.

```
SELECT column FROM table
LIMIT 10000

SELECT column FROM table
LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

in mysql you do as follows

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON_TBL LIMIT 0, 1000 

SELECT * FROM PERSON_TBL LIMIT 1000, 1000
```

Query 1 will fetch first 1000 records,

Query 2 will fetch next 1000 records

Syntax for limits clause

**LIMITS OFFSET, ROWCOUNT**

Where 
ROWCOUNT give number of row to fetch

OFFSET   gives from which row to fetch
more info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

TSQL

`SELECT TOP 10000` ...

PL/SQL

... `WHERE ROWNUM < 10000` ...

Answer (score 0):

in MySQL :

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10000
```

This will display the first 10000 results from the database.

```
 SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 10000, 20000
```

This will show records 10001, 10002, ... ,20000