# How can i apply group by after applying limit in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run the below query but it is wrong as per MySQL syntax.
I want to select the first 100 rows then want to apply group by to it.

```
select customerid from customer
limit 100
group by customerid
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Please research your inquiry before posting in accordance with [ask]. Duplicate of [Limit SQL query result in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399487/limit-sql-query-result-in-mysql)

Comment: Instead: `SELECT DISTINCT customerid FROM customer LIMIT 100;`. OR `SELECT customerid FROM (select customerid FROM customer LIMIT 100) GROUP BY customerid` to use the syntax you were aiming at.

Comment: I don't see what purpose group by is serving here especially since there is no aggregation . Can you create sample data and expected output based on a lower limit?

Comment: @P.Salmon this is a small part of a big query.

Comment: why we are not able to apply the limit before group by?

Comment: According to specs, limit is done after grouping. To force your desired behavior, use a sub query.

Comment: A completely meaningless query. LIMIT without ORDER BY will return **some** 100 rows from all existing ones.

Comment: my question is not whether the query is meaningless or not
question is different don't go to what query is, try to understand the problem if you can.

Comment: Are the customerid unique? you could improve this question by adding sample data for 10 rows and reducing limit to an appropriate level to simulate your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? You need to add an aggregation column for it to work.

```
SELECT customerid
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   customer
        LIMIT  100) sub1
GROUP  BY sub1.customerid;
```

Comment: it's not necessary to add an aggregation function, It will still work.

Comment: That's awesome!

Comment: 'It will still work.' - only because mysql allows (other rdbms don') it so long as only_full_group_by is not set also without order by in subquery there is no guarantee that you will get the first 100 customerid and WHY would you need a group by are the customerid not unique?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: customer-id isn't unique. @DarshitParmar answered has resolved my query.
I have to use a subquery in order to use group by with limit.
as the limit is done after grouping.
Thanks

Comment: @Kakarot you can just mark my solution as accepted answer.