# How pagination works in php

Tags: php, pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP/MySQL Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095474/php-mysql-pagination)

I have a website where i am using mysql database. I want to use pagination to view data's in my website. I got lots of pagination script from net but those scripts are not working properly. Now i am trying to make my own simple pagination,can you help me.I dont understand the logic of how pagination works. In some scripts there is a $GET['page'] what is it? .Can you please suggest a simple pagination script also.

Comment: Maybe you should learn PHP first if you don't know what $_GET does

Comment: `$_GET['page']` is most likely the page number that the user wants to view.  It is sent to a php script using the `$_GET()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination is a problem that can be solved in at least a couple of ways:

- At the database level
- At the template level (chunk array etc)

Often the page that should currently be displayed is passed in via `GET` parameters such as `$_GET['page']` like in your example.

To do this at the database level you will be interested in MySQLs `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Pagination isn't something that is included in PHP, so any questions or answers would have to be very specific to your implementation. I would recommend reading some more tutorials and have a couple listed from decent PHP tutorial sites.

#### OO Based - Yeah!

[How to Paginate Data with PHP](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/)

#### Function Based - Boo!

[Basic Pagination](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination)

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['page']` will refer to a page parameter in the url

e.g.
http://www.test.com/mypagination.php?page=1
so here `$_GET['page'] = '1'`

you can then use that number to determine which results to get and could also use it to build links to previous and next pages

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, pagination works this way:

if you want to show 10 results per page, for a given 'P' page you should get 10 results starting on the (P-1)*10 result. In other words, you should get the first 10 results after the first (P-1)*10 results. This way if you are in page:

1 -> get first 10 after first 0*10 = results from 0 to 10;

2 -> get first 10 after first 1*10 = results from 10 to 20;

3 -> get first 10 after first 2*10 = results from 20 to 30;

...

That $_GET[] is a global variable that allows you to get the parameters passed by GET method. You can also use $_REQUEST[] for the same thing or $_POST[] for input fields of a form.