# Java Data base query/update for large amount of data

Tags: java, database, jdbc

What is the best way to implement the following scenario?

I need to call/query a data base table containing millions of records from a java application. Then for each records in the table, my application should call a third party API and get a status field as response. Then my application should again update each row in the table with the information (status) from the API.

Note - I am trying to figure out a method to do this in the best possible way. I understand that querying all the records together is not the best way forward.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to eat the elephant in one bite. Chunk it. Heard of pagination? Use it. See here: [MySQL pagination without double-querying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818567/mysql-pagination-without-double-querying)

Comment: Yes, I have heard of pagination. I am trying to find out the best possible solution to my problem. It is never my intention to query and fetch all the records in one go. I was trying to figure out whether there is some parallel approach rather than a sequential one.

Comment: parallel would not buy you much. You will see bottlenecks at one or more level -- either sluggish Java performance, memory overhead, or RW slowness at your RDBMS level. If you want to churn out big stuff and fast, NoSQL approaches may help you. Even there I would suggest pagination, but since RW is blazing fast it will give you lot less latency than regular RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

you can use oracle feature such as SQL loader, Data pumping Called via JDBC or script..

Comment: you use the below link.. 
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ

Write into a script & call via JDBC API such execute()

Answer (score 0):

Databases are not designed to update millions of records via Java API repeatedly. This can take many minutes.  If this is not enough, you may need to use a dataset embedded in Java (either caching or replacing your database)

Comment: :I understand. I wanted to know what is the best approach for such a task.