# Mysql database parameter

Tags: php, mysql, database, parameters, pagination

I have a task to finish for building a website, but I don't really understand the questions.

1. A page that is controlled through a parameter. This parameter determines the data on the page as selected from a MySQL database.
2. A gallery of at least 9 images that are obtained from a server. A good solution will be capable of pagination if there are lots of images available.

Any help would be great!

Comment: http://us2.php.net/docs.php, start reading.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL pagination without double-querying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818567/mysql-pagination-without-double-querying)

This is a duplicate.  If you are going to limit how many you have in place, You didn't specify how the parameter was being set, but a generic $_REQUEST would get you the GET or POST.

You also didn't specify the web services that could be in front, if it's apache mod-rewrite changing the URL to a GET request, you would have to design the mod-rewrite for that.

somedomain.com/script.php?get_variable=4

obtain the data from your MySQL database/table by first validating the input from the parameter, and you're set.

Or was your question was for us to write you the program without parameter values or full stack that handles parameter parsing?